# Select different table fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I use rails 4 and mysql. I have two Recipe and Category models.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, message: "deve ser único"
  validates_presence_of :name, message: "can't be blank"
end

class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

The Recipe fields are: id, title, resume, and category_id which is the reference for category.

Category fields are: id and name

I'm trying to make a query that through the Recipe table I get as a result all the fields of the two tables. I am trying to do this with the following query:

> Recipe.joins("INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id =
>   recipes.category_id").includes("category")

But the result gives me results only from the Recipe table. The result is:

> Recipe id: 1, title: "ababa", resume: nil, created_at: "2018-02-07
>   23:16:19", updated_at: "2018-02-07 23:16:19", category_id: 9

How can I make all the data in the two tables appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
recipes = Recipe.includes(:category) # Get all recipes and their categories
recipe = Recipe.includes(:category).find_by(id: 1) # Get one recipe with id = 1
```

The **includes** is not mandatory, but makes an eager loading.

Then you can handle one or many recipes. For a specific recipe you can get the category.

```
catname = recipe.category.name # Name of the category of one recipe

catnames = [] # Empty array
recipes.each do |r|
  catnames << r.category.name # Add name of category to array of names
end
```

Note: The answer by Subash was almost ok, but the first statement returns an array of recipes (where returns many objects), and not a unique recipe. That's why you cannot get the category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes` to preload associations data, so you can do

```
recipe = Recipe.includes(:category).where....
category = recipe.category
```

Comment: When i use Recipe.includes(:categories) i have the following mesage: ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'categories' was not found on Recipe; perhaps you misspelledit?

Comment: Can you try that again, had a typo, it should be `Recipe.includes(:category)`

Comment: When i try Recipe.includes(:category) i have: [#<Recipe id: 1, title: "ababa", resume: nil, created_at: "2018-02-07 23:16:19", updated_at: "2018-02-07 23:16:19", category_id: 9>]>, I can not get the data from the category table ... only the recipe

Comment: you already hava `category` data loaded in the result object, just do `result.category`

Comment: humm ... now I understand ... but when I try recipe.category I get:
NoMethodError:   Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = 9
undefined method `category' for #<Recipe::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055ec6c6df160>
        from (irb):94

Comment: recipe =Recipe.includes(:category).joins("INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = recipes.category_id")

After i am doing recipe.category

Comment: why are you doing inner joins, if you need all data you can just do `Recipe.includes(:category).all` or if you need to filter by something `Recipe.includes(:category).where(something: value)`

Comment: hum...i try with Recipe.includes(:category).all and i have the same error undefined method `category'

Comment: if you do an `all` you get a list of recipes so you have to iterate over them and then get `category` from each recipe

Answer (score 1):

Correct a bit from Subash

```
recipes = Recipe.includes(:category).where ...
recipes.each do |recipe|
  # category you need is here
  category = recipe.category
end
```